# setup a Plutus project use haskell.nix Error on Mac M1

Tags: plutus, haskell, nix, m1

I'm trying to set up a Plutus project with flake on my Macbook by [IOHK document](https://input-output-hk.github.io/haskell.nix/tutorials/getting-started-flakes.html)

I did the following steps:

1. create default.nix
2. enter command `nix flake init --template templates#haskell-nix --impure`
3. `nix develop`
   and then I got error bellow:

> error: a 'x86_64-linux' with features {} is required to build '/nix/store/n1aq309bp7jm9kkv7wi88jrxyjr09apa-cabal.project.drv', but I am a 'x86_64-darwin' with features {benchmark, big-parallel, nixos-test}
> (use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)

I'm a newbie, I'm learning how to create a project that is scalable, easy to test, and develop. if anyone can solve it please help me! Thanks!

Comment: Do you have `nix` installed? The best way of getting all Plutus features is building this repo `https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps` using `nix`.